# Android Studio installs only 64 bit executables?

Tags: android-studio

I installed the latest release of Android Studio (2.2.2) on my Ubuntu 32 bits and I found that all the executable are compiled for a 64 bit architecture.

For example:

```
$>file aapt
aapt: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=b090905d7de6a44b1e136a3d8b819569a6d4f9cb, not stripped
```

Anybody knows if Android Studio is only released for 64 bit architectures or if there is a specific 32 bit installation link hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32-bit OSes are not supported.

See the last message in the thread, posted by a Google member:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230623

> In general we don't support 32-bit Linux distributions, see the "System Requirements" section on https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.